# Where does µC programming belong?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I have some questions about µC and DSP programming but I don't know where these kind of question belong? Pure programming question belong to "stackoverflow" forum but DSP and µC are related to "Electronic engineering" forum.

Does "Electronic engineering" include low-level, embedded and real-time programming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Low-level programming, especially programming related to interfacing with external circuits is very appropriate for EE. Topics related to real-time systems are also appropriate. We also handle some DSP here, but there's also a separate [DSP.SE](https://DSP.stackexchange.com/) for the more application-specific questions.